# pass some variable of a row in Vue.js as parameters to vue.js method and send out using axios

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js

I have a web app, used Django as backend, Vue.js for the frontend.
In the cell, that's a button  for every row, which is supposed to get the detail info of the row after click.
So I want to pass some variable of  a row in Vue.js as parameters to  Vue.js method.

But I failed to do that, when I tried to click the button, it always submitted the form, but I have added type="button" already.

```
                <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(row, index) in filteredRows" :key="`isbn-${index}`">
                <td name="`title_${index}`" v-html="highlightMatches(row.title)">{{ row.title }}</td>
                <td v-html="highlightMatches(row.author)">{{ row.author }}</td>
              
               <td><button type="button" v-on:click="greet( $event, {{ row.title }})">Greet</button></td>
                <td name="`discipline_code_course_code_${index}`"  bgcolor= "white"><div contenteditable></div></td>
                          </tr>
            </tbody>

<script>
             const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data:() => ({
            filter: '',
            rows: book_rows
        }),

        methods: {
                      greet: function (event, title) {
                alert(title);   #undefined when debug
                this.$http.post(
    '/check_code/',
    { title: title }
  );

}

        },
</script>
```

How could I pass  some variable of  a row in Vue.js as parameters to  Vue.js method and send out using axios?

Comment: You should use @click or v-on:click for event handling instead of onclick in vue. Can you please try this ?

Comment: I have tried, but ajax can not work in that case

Comment: Are you using a backend templating language such as django or Jinja templating, that's stripping the `{{ bracketed }}` definitions before your Vue JS is using them?

Comment: I used django as backend

Comment: The code `v-on:click="greet( $event, {{ row.title }})"` might need inspecting, as if that's your title - you're applying it slightly differently in the row above: `v-html="highlightMatches(row.title)` . If it is a backend var, it needs speechmarks - if it's frontend, remove the brackets I think

Comment: @Glycerine  How could I deal with that if Django stripped the bracketed }} definitions before Vue JS is using them

Comment: @django okay, if you're using django - ensure it's not stripping those placeholders (the HTML template) before the JS can see and use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `verbatim` tag, to ensure django does not *strip* those attributes from the template before JS uses them: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim

Wrap you JS template (currently within your django served HTML file) with the verbatim tag to ensure the bracketed vars are *not* parsed by django:

```
{% verbatim %}
<div>{{ app.jsVars }}</div>
{% endverbatim %}
```

You can check this by inspecting the source code of the produced HTML page (right click view source) - and your JS template variables should be there.

---

Quick note:

The code `v-on:click="greet( $event, {{ row.title }})"` might need inspecting, as if that's your title - you're applying it slightly differently in the row above:

```
v-html="highlightMatches(row.title)
```

If it is a backend var, it needs speech-marks:

```
v-on:click="greet( $event, '{{ row.title }}')"
```